# Filtering Rows with duplicate column values

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table, boolean, filtering

I was cleaning a dataset for class. I noticed there were some negative values. Some rows with this condition also have the same id name in two columns 2 and 3.

I'm stumped. I'm trying to draft out a code, but unsure where should I start. I would love to get advice. I couldn't find anything similar.

Below is a sample table similar to the table I have.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,2,4,7,8), B=c(2,2,4,9,9), C=c(0,1,5,3,4))
```

Do I use the ifelse () nested within a filter()? I want to filter a data table without rows that have duplicate values in columns A and B. Using the table above as an example, what code would result in getting back rows 1, 4 and 5?

(sorry, above example keeps coming up as code and not a table.)

Comment: I don't understand your logic for filtering. Based on what condition do you want to dismiss rows 2 and 3? Are you looking for `df %>% filter(A != B)` with package `dplyr`?

Comment: If you just want to filter rows 2 and 3 do: `df[-c(2:3), ]`. Otherwise you would need to specify the filtering logic.

Comment: Hi, To clarify, I found some of my rows have duplicate columns. If I use filter(), what would people recommend I do to filter rows that do not have duplicates in columns A & B?

Comment: @TimTeaFan I haven't thought about indexing.  I'll look it up and learn more about this, thank you!

Comment: @MartinGal Oh! I didn't consider a boolean! I'm going to try it now. Thank you!

Comment: `dplyr`'s filtering always uses booleans/expressions that return booleans. :-)

Comment: My class barely touched on `dplyr` but I wished I took it upon myself to read up on it. I was distracted trying to figure out difftime that everything else went bye-bye. :D

Answer (score 1):

Up to now, the question has not received a proper answer.

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to know how to remove / filter out those rows where the columns `A` and `B` have identical values. Or, in other words how to keep those rows where `A` and `B` are different.

This is a basic question for which different approaches are available in R:

#### base R

```
df[df$A != df$B, ]
```

or

```
subset(df, A != B)
```

#### dplyr

as already mentioned in [Martin Gal's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68562833/filtering-rows-with-duplicate-column-values#comment121170960_68562833)

```
dplyr::filter(df, A != B)
```

#### data.table

as the question was tagged with [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)

```
data.table::setDT(df)[A != B]
```

All return rows 1, 4, and 5, e.g.,

> ```
>   A B C
> 1 1 2 0
> 4 7 9 3
> 5 8 9 4
> ```

There is no `ifelse()` required.

#### Data

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = c(1, 2, 4, 7, 8),
  B = c(2, 2, 4, 9, 9),
  C = c(0, 1, 5, 3, 4)
)
```

Comment: This is a great list of solutions! I can also think of several instances these could apply to. Thank you very much!